# Hover text for plotly r candlestick chart

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to make using of candlestick chart to represent a model output . So I am trying to plot the actual,modeled, and upper and lower values using a candelstick chart in plotly.  As per the given example for plotly r the hover always show open,close,high,low. Could I changed this hover text to custom text. Thank you.

```
library(plotly)
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("AAPL",src='yahoo')

# basic example of ohlc charts
df <- data.frame(Date=index(AAPL),coredata(AAPL))
df <- tail(df, 30)

p <- df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Date, type="candlestick",
          open = ~AAPL.Open, close = ~AAPL.Close,
          high = ~AAPL.High, low = ~AAPL.Low) %>%
  layout(title = "Basic Candlestick Chart")
```

Comment: Could this not help? https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/#custom-hover-text

Comment: I was able to add the custom hover text but still get the default candlestick hover text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question.
Here I try to customize the hover text of the candlestick chart using the following code:

```
p <- df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Date, type="candlestick",
          open = ~AAPL.Open, close = ~AAPL.Close,
          high = ~AAPL.High, low = ~AAPL.Low,
          text = paste("Text1:",df$AAPL.Open,"<br>Text2:",df$AAPL.Close),
          hoverinfo='text') %>%
  layout(title = "Basic Candlestick Chart")
```

With my `plotly_4.8.0.9000` I get a candlestick chart but no hover text appears.
Using `plotly_json` it is possibile to inspect the JSON sent to `plotly.js`.
The `hoverinfo` attribute should be set to `'text'` but in `data -> 0 -> hoverinfo` one can see that it contains an array of strings `'text'`.

[image]

A possibile solution is to manually set `hoverinfo` to `'text'`:

```
pltyobj <- plotly_build(p)
pltyobj$x$data[[1]]$hoverinfo <- "text"
pltyobj
```

[image]